# Access NameBinding value inside my filter

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I've a filter for my REST service. A normal authentication filter.

Now I need to pass a boolean in to it. From this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html) I got to this point:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthenticationFilterBinding {

    boolean checkAccountStatus() default true;
}
```

And in my filter implementation I've:

```
@AuthenticationFilterBinding
@Provider
@Priority(FilterPriority.AUTHENTICATION_PRIORITY)
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AuthenticationAbstractFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

    // Here I need to check the value of checkAccountStatus() defined in the code above.

    // How can I access that value?

    // My filter logic goes here
    }
}
```

On my endpoints I've something like:

```
@POST
@Path("/photo")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@AuthenticationFilterBinding(checkAccountStatus = false)
@ManagedAsync
public void setUserPhoto(@Suspended AsyncResponse ar, @FormDataParam("image") InputStream fileStream, @HeaderParam(Constant.HEADER_USER_ID) long userId) { 
    // ...
}
```

My problem is that I need to check the value of `checkAccountStatus` inside my filter and that is my problem here, how can I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

In the filter use reflection to access the value. Like this:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        final ExtendedUriInfo extendendUriInfo = (ExtendedUriInfo) requestContext.getUriInfo();

        boolean checkAccountStatus = extendendUriInfo
                                                    .getMatchedResourceMethod()
                                                    .getInvocable()
                                                    .getHandlingMethod()
                                                    .getAnnotation(AuthenticationFilterBinding.class).checkAccountStatus();
}
```

Hope this may help someone.

Note, this is using reflection and reflection is **slow**. I wouldn't use this on a big filter (like authentication, a filter you'll use pretty much everywhere)... it will slow down your app/website.

I ended up creating a new filter just for that specific case. It's a trade off.